# FactoryGirl.create always fail in spec controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

So I have users model

I create it with scaffolding

the test is passed in model spec but it always fail in controller spec

my users_controller_spec

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::V1::UsersController, type: :controller do
  describe "GET #show" do
    before(:each) do
      @user = FactoryGirl.create :user
      get :show, id: @user.id
    end
  it { should respond_with 200 }
  end
end
```

my User's FactoryGirl

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name "MyString"
    sex_id 1 
  end
end
```

I can create user from my console and from my user model spec

```
FactoryGirl.create :user
```

but it always fail when I try to create it from my controller spec

```
  1) Api::V1::UsersController GET #show 
 Failure/Error: @user = FactoryGirl.create :user

 ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey:
   PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "users" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_12f007df76"
   DETAIL:  Key (sex_id)=(1) is not present in table "sexs".
   : INSERT INTO "users"
  # ------------------
 # --- Caused by: ---
 # PG::ForeignKeyViolation:
 #   ERROR:  insert or update on table "users" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_12f007df76"
 #   DETAIL:  Key (sex_id)=(1) is not present in table "sexs".
 #   /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.8/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/configuration.rb:18:in `block in initialize'
```

Comment: The error message says _you don't have a sexs record with id 1_.

Comment: yeah I have two models with almost same attributes but that model pass the test but this model fail, I'm trying to rewrite my code from start hope this issue will be fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can create users using the console because your development database has the table "sexs" filled with info, but your test database does not. To find out if this is what is happening, open your console in the test environment and try to create a user.

Comment: At least in the projects I have worked in, there was a different database for running the tests. In order to open a console in the test environment use `RAILS_ENV=test rails c` instead of `rails c`

Comment: yeah you were right I cannot create it in test environment, but what make me confuse is why I can create it in another model with same attributes sex_id, the another model is devise model btw

Comment: `rails c test` would also open the test console